# 2-dimensional array not working

Tags: java, arrays, object, for-loop, arraylist

I have a 2 dimensional array gets a specific animal from a text file, but for some reason it's not working at all. I have checked for any errors but I get no errors just no output. It just keeps outputting "could not find file" which i know is not true

TEXT

```
Hat, dog, cat, mouse
Cow, animal, small, big, heavy
Right, left, up, down ,behind
Bike, soccer, football, tennis, table-tennis
```

CODE

```
try {
    animals = new Scanner(new File("animals.txt"));
    // code for number of lines start
    File file =new File("animals.txt");

    if(file.exists()){

        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(fr);

        int linenumber = 0;

        while (lnr.readLine() != null){
            linenumber++;
        }

        lnr.close();

        // code for number of lines end

        String[][] animal = new String [linenumber][];

        for (int i = 0; i < linenumber; i++) {
            String line = animals.nextLine();
            String [] oneRowAnimals = line.split(",");
            for(int j=0; j<oneRowAnimals.length; j++) {

                // Here you are storing animals
                animal[i][j] = oneRowAnimals[j];
            }
        }
        // Now you can access them by index.

        System.out.println(animal[2][2]);

    } else{
        System.out.println("File does not exists!");
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("could not find file");
}
```

Comment: animal.txt has to be on classpath.

Comment: I would suggest removing the try catch and look at what exception it is throwing. Or at least changing the Exception to the specific error thrown when file is not found. In this case it is currently catching all Exceptions without any discrimination.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize your sub-arrays with a size. Attempting to access these uninitialized sub-arrays by index results in a NullPointerException. Insert the code:

```
animal[i] = new String[oneRowAnimals.length];
```

after the line:

```
String [] oneRowAnimals = line.split(",");
```

As was suggested in the comments, it is very helpful when debugging code such as this to avoid swallowing all types of exceptions. Catching specific exceptions that may be thrown by code in the try block, or at least printing a more informative message in your catch block, would be a good idea.